# Python Qt Creator new project base class QMainWindow not showing dynamic form.ui

Tags: python, qt, dynamic, qmainwindow

I've installed Qt Creator v9.0.1 on Ubuntu 22.04 / Windows 10 and try to create a new project which shows an empty frame and not the loaded `form.ui`:

[Screenshot](https://i.snipboard.io/yIirHB.jpg)
[Screencapture](https://gfycat.com/longglaringdormouse)

**Testcase**:

- File | New Project:

  - Application (Qt for Python) | Window UI - Dynamic load:

    - PySide version: PySide6
    - Base class: QMainWindow

Default generated **mainwindow.py**:

```py
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtCore import QFile
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "form.ui"
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MainWindow()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Default generated **form.ui**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar"/>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I expected the `form.ui` window size with menubar and statusbar instead of an empty small window. Same behavior on Windows and Ubuntu 22.04 Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what you see (i.e the small empty window) and, if possible, what you want it to show instead? Also have you checked that the form.ui line points to the correct file (this line `path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "form.ui"` )?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As new user I've insufficient credits to post an image, but here is the link: https://snipboard.io/yIirHB.jpg

> Also have you checked that the form.ui line points to the correct file (this line path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "form.ui" )? 

Yes, the path is correct (generated by New Project) and I also tried an absolute path.
Reproducible on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Related to issue https://forum.qt.io/topic/114865/qt-creator-and-pyside2-blank-window/13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-25807.

Problem solved as this is a bug in Qt Creator when creating a New Project with dynamic load and `QMainWindow` base class:

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtCore import QFile
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "form.ui"
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)

-        loader.load(ui_file, self)
+        widget = loader.load(ui_file, self)

        ui_file.close()

+        widget.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MainWindow()
-    # widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```